# How to install driver of Huwaei Modem E303C in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: linux, installation, driver, modem, ubuntu-13.04

I extracted the linux driver tar file in my desktop directory and the run following commands:

cd Desktop/driver
./install /home//Desktop/driver

and i got following errors:

```
DRIVER COPY START
STA_PATH_FLAG=.
STA_PATH_FULL=/home/pratik/Desktop/driver/install
START_PATH_DRIVER=/home/pratik/Desktop/driver
CURRENT install from ./install
INSTALL_PATH=/home/pratik/Desktop
DRIVER COPY END
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pratik/Desktop/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
rm -rf *.o *.ko *~ core* .dep* .*.d .*.cmd *.mod.c *.a *.s .*.flags .tmp_versions Module.symvers Modules.symvers *.order
/home/pratik/Desktop/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "clean" "/lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/usb"
rmmod -f hw_cdc_driver
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pratik/Desktop/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
make -C src/ modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pratik/Desktop/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
#/home/pratik/Desktop/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "modules" "/lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/usb"
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/pratik/Desktop/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/pratik/Desktop/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.o
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pratik/Desktop/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
make -C src/ install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pratik/Desktop/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
#install -m 744 -c hw_cdc_driver.o /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/net
#depmod -a
#modprobe hw_cdc_driver
/home/pratik/Desktop/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "install"
modprobe hw_cdc_driver
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pratik/Desktop/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
#[31;1m
Install NDIS driver failed.
The compiling environment is not all ready.
Please check gcc, make and kernel buid(/lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build) to be all installed?
#[34;1mNow please enter any key to finish other installations.#[0;0m
#[31;1mNDIS is disabled, and only Modem can be used.#[0;0m
USBSERIAL_TARGET_PATH = 
ACM_TARGET_PATH = 
have usb_modeswitch rules to HUAWEI DataCard: COUNT=1
RULESFILE =/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
COUNT_START=1
COUNT_END=0
3
ttyUSB%n COUNT=3
2-1.3:1.3 unbind and bind option
COUNT_END=2
2-1.3:1.2 unbind and bind option
COUNT_END=1
2-1.3:1.0 unbind and bind option
COUNT_END=0
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc5.d
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc3.d
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc2.d
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc4.d
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem of installation of linux driver of huwaei modem in my ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0):

Here you see the "how to install driver":

```
bhaskar@bhaskar:~$ cd Desktop/driver
bhaskar@bhaskar:~/Desktop/driver$ sudo ./install
old path =/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver
FATAL: Module option is in use.
DRIVER COPY START
STA_PATH_FLAG=.
STA_PATH_FULL=/home/bhaskar/Desktop/driver/install
START_PATH_DRIVER=/home/bhaskar/Desktop/driver
CURRENT install from ./install
INSTALL_PATH is not set ,auto install
INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/Mobile_Partner
INSTALL_PATH is another path
rm /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver
DRIVER COPY END
ls: cannot access /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver
Error: missing module or filename.
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:753 kmod_module_remove_module: could not remove 'cdc_ether': No such file or directory
Error: could not remove module cdc_ether: No such file or directory
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:753 kmod_module_remove_module: could not remove 'usbnet': Resource temporarily unavailable
Error: could not remove module usbnet: Resource temporarily unavailable
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:753 kmod_module_remove_module: could not remove 'hw_cdc_driver': No such file or directory
Error: could not remove module hw_cdc_driver: No such file or directory
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
rm -rf *.o *.ko *~ core* .dep* .*.d .*.cmd *.mod.c *.a *.s .*.flags .tmp_versions Module.symvers Modules.symvers *.order
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "clean" "/lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/usb"
rmmod -f hw_cdc_driver
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:753 kmod_module_remove_module: could not remove 'hw_cdc_driver': No such file or directory
Error: could not remove module hw_cdc_driver: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
make -C src/ modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
#/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "modules" "/lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/usb"
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build SUBDIRS=/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.o
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘__check_ncm_prefer_32’:
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:113:1: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘__check_ncm_prefer_crc’:
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:116:1: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘__check_rt_debug’:
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:128:1: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘hw_change_mtu’:
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:899:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘rx_tlp_parse’:
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:1085:7: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘tx_complete’:
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:1663:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘cdc_ncm_config’:
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2036:24: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2037:3: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2037:3: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2041:21: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2057:3: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘hw_cdc_probe’:
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2589:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘dbg’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
make -C src/ install
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
#install -m 744 -c hw_cdc_driver.o /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/net
#depmod -a
#modprobe hw_cdc_driver
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "install"
modprobe hw_cdc_driver
FATAL: Module hw_cdc_driver not found.
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
make: *** [install] Error 2

Install NDIS driver failed.
The compiling environment is not all ready.
Please check gcc, make and kernel buid(/lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build) to be all installed?
Now please enter any key to finish other installations.
lNDIS is disabled, and only Modem can be used.
TARGET_PATH = 
TARGET_PATH = 
have usb_modeswitch rules to HUAWEI DataCard: COUNT=0
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc4.d
‘/etc/rc4.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc4.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc5.d
‘/etc/rc5.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc5.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc2.d
‘/etc/rc2.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc2.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc3.d
‘/etc/rc3.d/S99runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
‘/etc/rc3.d/K10runhwactivator’ -> ‘/etc/init.d/runhwactivator’
bhaskar@bhaskar:~/Desktop/driver$
```

and this is how to solve the problem:

The problem is here:

```
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:2589:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘dbg’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

I had a similar problem with another Huawei modem driver, and I fixed the source code.

First, let's find out where the hw_cdc_driver.c file is. Run the file command on all the files in the ~/Desktop/driver directory:

file *
You'll see some of them are "7-zip archive data" files. Run 7z l on each of them, to see the contents:

```
7z l data.bin
```

Maybe there are too many files, so you can just grep for the one you are looking for:

```
7z l data.bin | grep hw_cdc_driver.c
```

If you find it, then you need to extract the archive.

```
mkdir data_bin

mv data.bin data_bin
cd data_bin
7z x data.bin
rm data.bin
```

Now you have the contents of the archive in the data_bin directory. Search for the hw_cdc_driver.c file, open it, and go to line 2589 (the one from the error). You can just comment that line containing dbg (add a // in front of it) and save then close the file.

To pack the archive with the modified file, use 7z again:

```
cd data_bin
7z a data.bin data_bin
mv data.bin ..
```

Now you have replaced data.bin with the fixed file. Try to install again.

///I put just my experience with this modem..hope to be helpfur for you...

YOU CAN MERGE THIS PROBLEM WITH YOUR PROBLEM I HOPE TO BE USEFUL :)

you can also [follow link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DF8xI_DM9NY)

this is again [help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323031/how-to-install-ndis-driver-for-huawei-mobile-broadband-devices)